# Log4J 2 configuration: How to split log files by size and by day at the same time?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I need to create a new log file once a day, or if log file size become 250 MB. So how can i do this through log4j.properties file? Dividing by day is working, but if size become more than 250MB nothing happens.
My current property file is:

```
 # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=./logs/application_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=250000
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# configuration to print on console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the following log4j link https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/rolling-file.html, you have to add the following lines.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=250000
```

Note:

1. File Appender should be `RollingFileAppender`
2. Triggering Policy should be `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`

EDIT:

```
# Direct log messages to a log filelog4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.File=${LOG_DIR}/application.log
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=./logs/application_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
log4j.appender.rfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=250MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.append=true
```

You can refer complete example below.
https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-rolling-file-appender/

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for me, see my updated properties file :(

Comment: Just updated the answer in the edit section, please try now.